# Regex to find all <body> tags not written by server-side code

Tags: regex, tags, server-side, detection

I've been trying to create this Regex but it's driving me crazy. What I basically need is a regex that detects all `<body>` tags which are not written through my server-side code. My plan is to replace all those `<body>` tags by something like `<body><%=CallToFunction()%>`.

(This is part of a search & replace within `UltraEdit`.)

E.g:

```
<body>                                          //should be found
<body class="normal">                           //should be found
<body class="<% Response.Write("normal") %>"    //should be found
<html><body class="normal">                     //should be found

Response.Write("<body class=""normal"">")       //should not be found (a)
Response.Write(" <body>")                       //should not be found (b)
Response.Write("<html><body><h1>...")           //should not be found (c)

message = "<html><body>...</body></html>"       //should not be found (d)
Response.Write(message)

Response.Write("<html>
                <head></head>
                <body class=""normal"">
                    <h1>...</h1>")              //should not be found (e)
```

The regex I have currently is: `([^"]<body.*[^>]*>)`. But the problem there is that it will still find `<body>` tags with a space between the `<body>` and the `"` (see example `(a)`). It would also still find `(c)`.

And for `(e)` I am really clueless. Wondering if that is even possible to detect.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I now have `^(?!Response|")(<body.*[^>]*>)` which works pretty well. But it doesn't work when the `<body>` tag is indented in the document. So I'd need something like `<body` prepended by anything (or nothing) other than `Response` or `"`.

**ANSWER**

The regex I eventually ended up using was based on Michael Allen's answer and was:

`^(?!Response|")([\t ]*)(<body.*[^>]*>)`

It did not solve `(e)` but I guess I'll do some manual work for those cases then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure how you would deal with the last example but the following regex will match correctly with every other example you provided.

```
^(?!Response).*<body.*>
```

The trick here is using the Negative lookahead to knock out any matches that contains `Response` at the beginning.

Hopefully thats a start for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have added another one though which I forgot about and which will not work with this one though. Although it's a good start already! I didn't know about the negative lookaheads.

Comment: I accepted your answer Michael. I eventually found one that is doing the trick for me and it was based on your answer. So thanks for taking the time to respond. :)

Comment: Post it below so I can see how you did it, always good way to learn

Comment: I have already edited my question to include the final answer.